# How to add quotes to annotation in Kubernetes via Gitlab?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to add Prometheus path annotations to an application by passing variables through Helm.

But in the manifest, the path is written without quotes, because of this, I get the default path as in the screenshot
[image]

In the manifest, the path is written without quotes:

```
 metadata:
   annotations:
     cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: d180a62acc4887516c3894cee2987e8b40d42f24395df7d5400b9cdbacc5d3a4
     cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.105.206/32
     cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.105.206/32
     prometheus.io/path: /phd/demo-phd-graphql-router/actuator/prometheus
     prometheus.io/port: "8080"
     prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
```

Can you please tell me how to correctly specify the quotes for the path in the GitLab pipeline?

```
      --set-string podAnnotations."prometheus\.io/scrape"=true \
      --set-string podAnnotations."prometheus\.io/port"=8080 \
      --set-string podAnnotations."prometheus\.io/path"=/phd/demo-phd-graphql-router/actuator/prometheus
```

My lines in the pipeline:

Comment: Have you considered using a values.yaml and using `--values values.yaml` instead of `--set`?

Comment: We need to pass a lot of parameters, so we use variable passing.

Comment: If you need to pass a lot of parameters, then a values.yaml is definitely an option you should look at. Otherwise you will have a TON of --set parameters that makes it hard to read. Plus you can have different values.yaml files for different profiles (e.g. production., staging,test)